# Does "X is made of people" intend a joking tone?

Tags: puns

The essay [How to Make Pittsburgh a Startup Hub](http://paulgraham.com/pgh.html) reads:

> It said "people ages 25 to 29 now make up 7.6 percent of all residents, up from 7 percent about a decade ago." Wow, I thought, Pittsburgh could be the next Portland. It could become the cool place all the people in their twenties want to go live.
>
> ...
>
> What does that have to do with startups? **Startups are made of people**, and the average age of the people in a typical startup is right in that 25 to 29 bracket.

Does this sentence intend a joking tone, like "bread is made of dough, and startups are made of people"? Or it's purely neutral? I'm translating this, and in translation this makes a big difference.

Comment: Something that is obvious is not necessarily a pun. Without context that sentence doesn't seem very punny.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what [*pun*](https://www.google.co.in/search?&q=define+pun) means.

Comment: @Helmar I added some context to make it clearer.

Comment: It's meant to suggest that startups do not primarily rely on equipment, goods, or even money, but rather the individuals who form and work in it. It's similar to the maxim that a business' most important assets go home every night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the punny side. It appears to me that *"Startups are made of people"* simply means that startups are made up of people.

***Make (something) up*** — [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/make-something-up)

> 2. (**make up**) (Of parts) compose or constitute (a whole)
>      *"...water is made up of hydrogen and oxygen,..."*